# How to get the content from an uncompressed .docx file by using ifstream.open() and read() methods. office open xml, vc++

Tags: visual-c++, openxml, ifstream

I'm trying to build a suffix tree from a .docx file.

So first I unzipped the .docx file and then again created a .docx file with out compressing it. I used ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipOutputStream.SetLevel(0) method. Here I used C#.

This uncompressed .docx files can be opened without any error.

For the next step I used vc++. By using ifstream.open ("uncompressed.docx", ios::binary ); method I tried to open the file and store the content in a char array by using ifstream.read ( (char *)T, MAX_LENGTH - 1 ) method. But I could not get the actual content of  uncompressed.docx file. When I tried to print the content of the char array(T) it printed some formatting tags rather than printing the actual text content of the uncompressed.docx.

I could not figure out what is the actual file that ifstream.open() method opens.It is not the document.xml file.

Please tell me how to get the actual text content from the uncompressed.docx file using VC++.

Comment: The document.xml file is an XML document, whith lots of "formatting tags", indeed. What file are you trying to open?

Comment: I'm trying to open uncompressed.docx file. not the document.xml file. After unzipping the compressed.docx file it contains some xml files including document.xml file.But I didn't open it. instead of I zipped the folder without compressing it and again create an uncompressed version of the .docx file.

Comment: I don't understand. A docx is a collection of files. The text for the document is in one of theses files, stored in XML format. If you try to "open" a zipped folder renamed .docx, you won't get the actual text.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When we open a normal .docx file using  ifstream.open ("somename.docx", ios::binary ) method what is the exact file does it open?

Comment: It opens the file somename.docx, the same way you can open "foo.zip", or "bar.jar" or "foobar.cab".